# Certificate based authentication failure in Chrome

Tags: java, openssl, tomcat8

I have a JAX-WS web service which I want to protect using a certificate-based authentication.

I've got Tomcat 8 installed with APR, and OpenSSL.

I'm a newbie with SSL, so I decided to follow this guide http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/2014-04-09-Tomcat-SSL.pdf to create a self-signed certificate

My tomcat Connector is the following:

```
<Connector port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    maxThreads="150"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    SSLCertificateFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys-pdf\certs\localhost-cert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys-pdf\private\localhost-key.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\keys-pdf\cacert.pem"
    SSLCipherSuite="ALL" />
```

When accessing to my webapp using the default port (8080), I get automatically redirected to https://localhost:8443/webapp. Unfortunately, after selecting the certificate (and installing it in my browser), I get the following error (chrome):

[image: error 401]

Text message:
Estado HTTP 401 - Imposible autenticar mediante las credenciales suministradas
type Informe de estado
mensaje Imposible autenticar mediante las credenciales suministradas
descripción Este requerimiento requiere autenticación HTTP.

Which means (more or less):
HTTP 401 status - Unable to authenticate using the credentials supplied
type Status report
message Unable to authenticate using the credentials supplied
description This request requires HTTP authentication.

How can I solve this? Appreciate your help.

**Edit:**

SSL/TLS implementation was working properly, however, what wasn't ok was my web.xml configuration. I had been testing  options, so initially I tried BASIC.

My web.xml looked like this:

```
...
<security-constraint>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Operator Roles Security</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/padronExterno</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>operator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>    

</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Normal operator user</description>
    <role-name>operator</role-name>
</security-role>
...
```

Within tomcat-users.xml I had:

```
    <tomcat-users >
    ...
    <!-- Roles for BASIC authentication -->
    <role rolename="operator"/>
    <user username="username" password="passwd" roles="operator"/>
    ...
</tomcat-users>
```

And default engine for localhost in server.xml had the following realm:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>
```

This was working without any issue. After that, I tried the CLIENT-CERT. The problem was that I didn't remove the stuff related to BASIC auth-method:  and . That's why I was getting that 401 error.

Comment: You should add the text of the error message to the question, and not an image. I was not able to copy/paste it into Google translator. Also, indexing engines will not be able to index it so future visitors can find it.

Comment: I'm sorry @jww, I've just edited it and posted my solution.